# Jenkins Build Pipeline Scheduled Trigger

Tags: jenkins

How can a build pipeline be scheduled to execute at a certain time of the night just like a regular job can be?

Comment: Do you mean a pipeline from the build pipeline plugin? If yes its just a view  just add a "Build periodically" to the first job in your pipeline.Guess first job runs on "Poll SCM"?

Answer (score 56):

Declarative pipeline has `triggers` directive, one uses it like this:

```
triggers { cron('H 4/* 0 0 1-5') }
```

I took it from [Pipeline Syntax docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers)

Comment: FYI: this will build every branch that includes this line in its `Jenkinsfile`; i.e., if you have this in your `master` or `develop` branch and all in-progress feature branches, they will all trigger on this schedule.

Comment: @dwj which, in most cases is not what one wants!

Comment: While conditional triggers are not yet supported, some workaround exists see: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42643. Basically, you have to define a variable outside of the declarative pipeline `String cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "@hourly" : ""` and then pass the `cron_string` to the `cron` trigger. Works for me!

Comment: @dwj if this line is written only on the stage of the development branch it will trigger only the development branch? Am I right on that? Or do you mean even if I write the trigger proposed on the development stage it will rather build all the rest stages and branches. An alternative could be ```triggeredBy``` in when {} properties

Answer (score 35):

You can set the job parameters using the following syntax:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('H 23 * * *')])])
```

Adding this line to your build script or Jenkinsfile will configure the job to run every night at 11PM.

Comment: It does not work in scripted pipelines under jenkins 2.79 (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Undefined symbol ‘pipelineTriggers’)

Comment: @gileri - I've seen you make this comment in several places. Would you mind please clarifying? Do you mean that piplineTriggers will not work on versions below 2.79? Or that they do not work while running 2.79? I can read it both ways. We just updated to 2.150.2 and are having trouble getting our pipelineTrigger properties block to work.

Comment: @RobertRSeattle I could have better worded it. What I meant is it doesn't work on Jenkins 2.79; I haven't tried other versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In our case we just hadn't installed the proper pipeline plugin.

Comment: The proper pipeline being "Pipeline" (workflow-aggregator) ?
https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator

Comment: For anyone in the future that had the same issue that I had, where its failing syntax-wise, I needed some statement after the `@Library` in my Jenkinsfile. Since I was using the idea from @Clément MATHIEU of `string cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "@hourly" : ""` and then writing `properties...` it works for me.

Answer (score 29):

Complete Example (taken from docs)
Ref: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'triggers' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, ArtifactoryMavenBuild, MavenDescriptorStep` facin this error

Comment: You need to trigger a build once for the trigger to be added. Took me some time to realize that - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47539?focusedCommentId=317448&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-317448

Comment: Will this interfere with the standard behavior of building when the index is updated? Currently our pipeline has no triggers defined, but when new code is pushed, a build is triggered after the SCM scan occurs. If I put this in, will that override that behavior and only build on the periodic schedule?

Comment: @Jon You can have multiple triggers for a job/pipeline. Adding this scheduled trigger won't affect SCM scan trigger.

Comment: Thanks @SatishGadhave, I guess what I'm asking is, would this override any implicit behaviors? We have SCM scan trigger in project settings (every 5 minutes), which then runs the Jenkinsfile if there's a difference between source and index -- currently the Jenkinsfile has no triggers defined, so it will always run everything when the scan calls it. But by adding in an explicit trigger into the Jenkinsfile (for the cron scheduling), would we also need to add _another_ trigger for SCM scanning?

Comment: Hi, I'd have below referred jenkinsfile structure. How to add trigger in this case?:     ...plan = {
        stage('Build tests') {
            sh "docker build --network=host --build-arg CACHE_BUST=\$(date +%s) -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} ."
        }
        stage('Run tests') {.....

Answer (score 9):

Into the main job configuration of your pipeline (the first), set the "Build periodically" checkbox, and specify the schedule that you want.

follow the syntax indications.

> ```
> the field follows the syntax of cron (with minor differences). Specifically, each line consists of 5 fields separated by TAB or whitespace:
>  MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW
>  MINUTE   Minutes within the hour (0–59)
>  HOUR The hour of the day (0–23)
>  DOM  The day of the month (1–31)
>  MONTH    The month (1–12)
>  DOW  The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.
>
>  To specify multiple values for one field, the following operators are available. In the order of precedence,
>
>     * specifies all valid values
>     M-N specifies a range of values
>     M-N/X or */X steps by intervals of X through the specified range or whole valid range
>     A,B,...,Z enumerates multiple values
>
>  Examples:
>
>  # every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
>  H/15 * * * *
>  # every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
>  H(0-29)/10 * * * *
>  # once every two hours every weekday (perhaps at 9:38 AM, 11:38 AM, 1:38 PM, 3:38 PM)
>  H 9-16/2 * * 1-5
>  # once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December
>  H H 1,15 1-11 *
> ```

Comment: How would you do this for just a specific branch if using multibranch pipelines?

Comment: ^^ Adam Parkin: Could you just configure this build so that you're only filtering branches you're interested in building?

Comment: @ShowPony and @Adam,  this is a workarround. You could configure in a single pipeline job or free style job the build periodically trigger. When trigger launch, it will execute the branch job that you want of your multibranch pipeline.  For example, you schedule a job that launch every 15 minutes (H/15 * * * *)  _'build periodically property'_ a develop branch job of your pipeline multibranch in this way in a   `stage("schedule") {
    echo "Hello I want to execute develop branch from my multibranch"
    build '/my-multibranch-job-name/develop'
}`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run the job periodically for a specific branch using a multibranch pipeline you can do this in your Jenkinsfile:

```
def call(String cronBranch = 'master') {

    // Cron job to be run from Monday to Friday at 10.00h (UTC)
    String cronString = BRANCH_NAME == cronBranch ? "0 10 * * 1-5" : ""

    pipeline {
        agent any

        triggers {
            cron(cronString)
        }
        stages {
            stage('My Stage') {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to run this job manually the first time in order to be added.

Comment: Rafa could you please explain how this will trigger only the master branch for a multibranch pipeline. The syntax doesn't seem to apply for a multibranch pipeline. In my Jenkisfile i have when {} statements inside the pipeline {} object to define the branch. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This code is part of a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). For example, it could be defined in this file: `my-shared-library-repository/vars/myPipeline.groovy`

In a different repository, let's call it, `my-repository`, we can have a `Jenkinsfile` that will use this pipeline.

For example: `/my-repository/Jenkinsfile`:

```
@Library('my-shared-library-repository@1.0.0') _

myPipeline('master')
```

Once we already have this code merged in the `master` branch of `my-repository` if we run the job for the `master` branch in Jenkins, this cron job will be configured with the values for the cron job implemented in the `master` branch due to the value of BRANCH_NAME is `master`
[Check triggers - cron](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers)
This cron job will re-run periodically the current job, that means, the job for the `master` branch.

Another example:

We can call this pipeline like this:

`/my-repository/Jenkinsfile`

```
@Library('my-shared-library-repository@1.0.0') _

myPipeline('devel')
```

If we run the job for the `master` branch the cron job won't be configured, however, if we run the job for the `devel` branch, the cron job will be set, because the value of BRANCH_NAME is `devel`. We will have a cron task running the job for the `devel` branch periodically.