# How to run only one test every night in Jenkins Pipeline flow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have series of test in Jenkins Pipeline like `Integration test1`, `Integration test2`, `smoke test`, `End-to-End Test`. Out of these test I want only the `End-to-End Test` to run every night for master irrespective of the SCM changes.

For example refer attached picture of Pipeline flow [image]
In this I would like to run `End-to-End Test` every night where as other test should run whenever SCM commit happens. And `End-to-End Test` should take the latest available artifact from Master.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I have few test in Jenkins Pipeline flow, out of which I want to schedule only one test to run at night. How to do this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028761/jenkins-build-pipeline-scheduled-trigger might be usable, but you can't have periodic stages or pull-based stages.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling in Jenkins is applicable to jobs. You need to refactor the End-to-End Tests into a separate Job. It can be a simple free-style job or a pipeline job. Then, you can schedule this job by configuring the `Build Triggers > Build periodically`.

This job can also be invoked from the pipeline by using the build job dsl:

```groovy
build job: 'e2e-test', parameters: ...
```