# How to create multi cron triggers for Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a pipeline job which used to generate jOOQ jar from databases schemas and publish the jar to our maven repository. There're two strategies to publish the jars, one is to publish a SNAPSHOT version every ten minutes and the other is to publish a RELEASE version every day. So how to configure two cron triggers in one pipeline and how to distinguish between them in the stage?

edit:

We knew using `triggers` directive to config a cron trigger, however, what this question need to resolve is how to configure *two* `cron` trigger, and each trigger belongs to different `stage`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Build Pipeline Scheduled Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028761/jenkins-build-pipeline-scheduled-trigger)

Comment: ^ the discussion there seems related, despite the question not being an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks for your information, however, I have to say that my situation is different from that one. I knew the `triggers` directive, what this question need to resolve is how to configure two `cron` trigger, and how to trigger to execute different `stage`. whatever, thanks again. BTW, would you mind to undo downvote to let more people reach this question?

Comment: well, I don't think this is directly being supported by [triggers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers), at least not with a single trigger, because there is no way to tell apart the stages - and so you'll have to setup snapshot and release individually, so that they can be triggered individually. that may be quite bureaucratic way to do this... but probably the only option (and difficult to answer, as abstract as the question is - because it is completely unknown what is going on with that job).

Comment: triggering the job with `crontab` and HTTP might also be an option.. but it's still the problem, that on cannot tell it at which stage it has to stop... breaking the pipeline into two pieces seems to be the best option available.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, using both an external trigger(like HTTP) and a internal cron trigger works, we can use `when { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }` and `when { not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' } }` to decide which stage to be executed. It seems there's no builtin solution now yet, so I'll leave this question here and see any progress in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After valuable discus with @MartinZeitler, finally, we choose the following way to do this.

Because our Jenkins job is a multi-branch pipeline job, we can create another branch then modify the `Jenkinsfile`. Jenkins will discover the new branch and period execute it. What we need to do is merge the changes from the `master` branch to the new branch manually when necessary.